# How to enable the disabled menu items in matlab when user do an action

Tags: matlab, user-interface, matlab-guide

well I have created menubar using gui guide in matlab , I have created menu items and disabled them , Now I want to make them enabled after user choose an image ,can any one just guide me?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Well find the enable property and activate it! probably somehing like `menu.Enable=1;`

Comment: @Benoit_11, even in earlier version, you can get access to the dot notation by fetching the actual handle of an object (ex: `hp=handle(plot(0)) ; hp.YData=1:100 ; hp.Color='r'`)

Comment: @Barq, try to include at least the part of your code where you define your menubar. (Include it by editing your original post, not in comment please).

Comment: Oh I guess I'm mixing things up sorry about that; I had an error the other day about something like this I guess it was something else. I'll delete my comment then.